# why does parse function return o?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# programming and I recently bumped into one problem which looks pretty basic.I store the string value like SV_1 in the variable lastServiceNo and split it using Split function and the result is stored in string array called index.Basically index[1] has some numeric value bt as string. now I want to convert string into int. In the following code , it behaves as expected until parse function is encountered.I could not understand why does this parse function returning 0 as index[1] has some numeric value in it. Can somebody point the problem please??

```
public string GenerateServiceNo() {
    DataAccessLayer.DataAccessLayer dlObj= new DataAccessLayer.DataAccessLayer();
    string lastServiceNo = dlObj.GetLastServiceNo();
    string[] index = lastServiceNo.Split('_');
    int lastIndex = int.Parse(index[1]);
    return "SV_"+(lastIndex++).ToString();
}
```

Comment: If the 'read'-value is SV_1 and the return value (of the method) should be SV_2, then you need to first increase lastindex: ++lastIndex instead of lastIndex++.

Comment: my question is why does parse function returning 0, i put the breakpoint on  int lastIndex = int.Parse(index[1]); and found index[0] has some numeric value. why its not being able to convert it into int???

Comment: Did you place the breakpoint at 'int lastIndex' or 'return ....'? Your code should work.

Comment: on index[0] , indeed it should work but idk why is it returning 0

Comment: index[0] = SV and index[1] = 1. You also need to place the breakpoint on the 'return "SV_"+(lastIndex++).ToString();' line and then look at the value of lastIndex.

Comment: If the above comments don't solve your problem, please provide more information.

Comment: Try following : index[1].Trim()  You may have spaces at the beginning and/or and of string.

Comment: @jdweng int.Parse() accepts whitespaces at the beggining/end of the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**int.Parse(string s)** throws an exception if the number is too bug in terms of data size or the string "s" is not in the correct numerical format.

The format that this method accepts is **"**[ws][sign]**number**[ws]**"** where:

- [ws] is optional for one or more whitespace(" ")
- [sign] is optional for "+" or "-"

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) for the full reference.

Thus said, I can assure you that if int.Parse(index[1]) returns 0 then that means index[1] equals "[ws][sign]0[ws]" using the transcript above.

However, looking at your code, I can conclude that you're incrementing a local variable after assignment without using its incremented value afterwards. Perhaps you meant that this operation shouldn't be 0?

If that's the case then I believe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
public string GenerateServiceNo() 
{
    DataAccessLayer.DataAccessLayer dlObj= new DataAccessLayer.DataAccessLayer();

    string lastServiceNo = dlObj.GetLastServiceNo();
    string[] index = lastServiceNo.Split('_');
    int lastIndex = int.Parse(index[1]);

    return string.Format("SV_{0}", ++lastIndex);
}
```

Assuming index[1] == "0", this method will now return "SV_1".

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for, because I already described it in a comment. Perhaps your code makes it clear for Saroj.

Comment: No I still did not get what i was looking for , everything is working fine beside that parse function.I put the breakpoint and ran through the code and analyzed it but could not find the solution. My question is why is the parse function returning 0 when index[1]=2